# Multiple USB to RS485 FTDI Device ID

Tags: c++, windows-10, ftdi

I need some help. I'm programming a Win 10 App in C++/CX. I am using two USB to RS485 devices, both of which have the same VID number. In days of old, I could write a bit software and connect to ports using good old COMx etc.

I'm now following the example here [Serial Sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/serialuart) which uses the approach gathering the device info so when looking for connected devices, what I see in the list of available devices is the following.

> \?\FTDIBUS#VID_0403+PID_6001

Both devices have the same VID and PID. This leads to the problem of me being cable to connect to the correct USB device. I think my app is trying to connect to both devices at the same time?  Does anyone have any ideas about how I can resolve this hitch?

```
void MainPage::Get_Serial_Devices() {

cancellationTokenSource_Port1 = new Concurrency::cancellation_token_source();
cancellationTokenSource_Port2 = new Concurrency::cancellation_token_source();

// THIS USES ASYNCRONOUS OPERATION. GET A LIST OF SERIAL DEVICES AND POPULATE THE COMBO BOX
Concurrency::create_task(ListAvailablePortsAsync()).then([this](DeviceInformationCollection^ serialDeviceCollectioin)
{

    // serialDeviceCollection CONTAINS ALL SERIAL DEVICES FOUND, COPY INTO _deviceCollection
    DeviceInformationCollection^ _deviceCollection = serialDeviceCollectioin;

    // CLEAR EXISTING DEVICES FOR OUR OBJECT COLLECTION
    _availableDevices->Clear();

    // FOR EVERY DEVICE IN _deviceCollection
    for (auto &&device : _deviceCollection) {

        if (device->Name->Equals("USB-RS485 Cable")) {

            // CREATE A NEW DEVICE TYPE AND APPEND TO OUR OBJECT COLLECTION
            _availableDevices->Append(ref new Device(device->Id, device));

            Total_Ports++;

            this->DeviceLists->Items->Append(device->Id);


        }

    }

});





void MainPage::ConnectButton_Click(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e) {



if (Port1_Connected == false) {

    // CAST INDEX TO CORRELATING Device IN _availableDevices
    Device^ selectedDevice = static_cast<Device^>(_availableDevices->GetAt(Port_1_ID));



    // GET THE DEVICE INFO
    DeviceInformation^ entry = selectedDevice->DeviceInfo; 



    Concurrency::create_task(ConnectToSerialDeviceAsync_Port1(entry, cancellationTokenSource_Port1->get_token())).then([this]( ) {

        Get_Echo(); 
        Waiting_For_Ack = true;


    }); 

}


Concurrency::task<void> MainPage::ConnectToSerialDeviceAsync_Port1(DeviceInformation^ device, Concurrency::cancellation_token cancellationToken) {


// CREATE A LINKED TOKEN WHICH IS CANCELLED WHEN THE PROVIDED TOKEN IS CANCELLED
auto childTokenSource = Concurrency::cancellation_token_source::create_linked_source(cancellationToken);

// GET THE TOKEN
auto childToken = childTokenSource.get_token();


    // CONNECT TO ARDUINO TASK
    return Concurrency::create_task(SerialDevice::FromIdAsync(device->Id), childToken).then([this](SerialDevice^ serial_device) {

        try {



            _serialPort_Port1 = serial_device;

            TimeSpan _timeOut;  _timeOut.Duration = 10;

            // CONFIGURE SERIAL PORT SETTINGS

            _serialPort_Port1->WriteTimeout = _timeOut;
            _serialPort_Port1->ReadTimeout = _timeOut;

            _serialPort_Port1->BaudRate = 57600;

            _serialPort_Port1->Parity = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialParity::None;
            _serialPort_Port1->StopBits = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialStopBitCount::One;
            _serialPort_Port1->DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort_Port1->Handshake = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialHandshake::None;



            // CREATE OUR DATA READER OBJECT
            _dataReaderObject_Port1 = ref new DataReader(_serialPort_Port1->InputStream);
            _dataReaderObject_Port1->InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions::None;


            // CREATE OUR DATA WRITE OBJECT
            _dataWriterObject_Port1 = ref new DataWriter(_serialPort_Port1->OutputStream);


            this->ConnectButton->IsEnabled = false;
            this->DisconnectButton->IsEnabled = true;


            // KICK OF THE SERIAL PORT LISTENING PROCESS
            Listen_Port1();



        }

        catch (Platform::Exception^ ex) {

            this->Error_Window->Text = (ex->Message);

            CloseDevice(PORT_1);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[FT_PROG](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities/FT_Prog_v3.6.88.402%20Installer.exe) is a free EEPROM programming utility for use with FTDI devices.  It is used for modifying EEPROM contents that store the FTDI device descriptors to customize designs.

The full FT_PROG User Guide can be downloaded [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_124_User_Guide_For_FT_PROG.pdf).